# how to run my .vimrc file without typing :source ~\.vimrc each time i open my vim

Tags: vim

I am a Windows user and I am using VIM . I have my .vmrc file in `C:users/username/.vimrc`. Each time I open vim from my windows terminal I must type `:source ~\.vimrc` to load my .vimrc file but i want to load my .vimrc file automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rename the file to `_vimrc`. Quoting from vim's `:help vimrc` internal documentation:

```
    Places for your personal initializations:
            Unix            $HOME/.vimrc or $HOME/.vim/vimrc
            MS-Windows      $HOME/_vimrc, $HOME/vimfiles/vimrc
                            or $VIM/_vimrc
```

(This does not apply if you're using the Cygwin installation of vim. Since Cygwin emulates a Unix environment, Cygwin's vim looks for `$HOME/.vimrc`.)